# Convert regular date time yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm format to Epoch timestamp excluding the seconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to convert `2014-10-31 11:28` (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm) to Epoch timestamp in Bash without the seconds. I am using the below code

```
echo s_unixtime=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$s_date $s_time" "+%s")
```

where

```
s_date = 2014-10-31
s_time = 11:28
```

The result is coming randomly as `1414780083` which is the epoch time of `2014-10-31 11:28:03`

The expected result is `1414780080`.

I am new to Shell Scripting. Please need help

Comment: `date -d "2014-10-31 11:28" +%s`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have used s_unixtime=$(date -d "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$s_date $s_time" "+%s") its not working. Is there any syntax error that I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps you should hard code `00` seconds: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00"`.

Comment: running `date -d "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$s_date" "$s_time" "+%s"` (note the additional dbl-quotes at end/beginning of `s_date`, `s_time`), my old system gives me an error message. AND I notice that you have `:` in your template string, and also in you variable values, I think if you really want to pass in variables, instead of just using one variable for right after `-d`, you'll have to supply separate variables for each element of `%Y-%m...`. Good luck.

Comment: `date -d "$s_date $s_time" +%s`

Comment: There you go! now with @jww's `:00` ... `date -d "$s_date $s_time":00 +%s` might do the trick. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I tried with    s_unixtime=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$s_date $s_time":00 "+%s") .   Its not working. I am a novice and I am probably doing a silly mistake. Please correct me.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to specify the format instead of just letting `date -d "$s_date" +%s` handle the date for you? `date` can interpret a wide set of formats on its own. `s_date="2014-10-31 11:28"; date -d "$s_date" +%s` works just fine.

Comment: If you want it in `UTC` either use, e.g. `s_date="2014-10-31 11:28:00"; date -u -d "$s_date" +%s` or use it as `s_date='TZ="UTC" 2014-10-31 11:28'; date -d "$s_date" +%s` Either was will work.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes I am using a loop and passing multiple values to use that result in a grep command

Comment: Well, of course, the comments were by way of example, `s_date="2014-10-31"; s_time="11:28"; date -u -d "$s_date $s_time" +%s` will work equally well. You can use it in your *command substitution*, e.g. `s_unixtime=$(date -u -d "$s_date $s_time" +%s)` as well.

Comment: Is this solved? @DavidC.Rankin 's comments are completely on target. Your example switched from using `date -d ...` to `date -j -f ...` .wth!? My version of `date` doesn't have a `-j` option, but my original comments about mismatch of `:` (and `-`) chars in you input against the mask containing the same chars still applies. Don't make it so overcomplicated! ;-) OK? and Good luck.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin your solution worked. Apologies for the late reply.